# Running multiple independent queries simultaneously in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I wanted to know whether it is possible to run independent queries simultaneously in a loop. for eg:

```
begin
for I in (select class_id from school) loop
insert into mast_tab(
select * from class1);
insert into mast_tab(
select * from class2);
insert into mast_tab(
select * from class3);
insert into mast_tab(
select * from class4);
insert into mast_tab(
select * from class5);
commit;
end loop;
end;
```

In the above block all the queries will be executed one by one when the loop condition is true.  Based on the loop value, is it possible to run all the queries simultaneously while the queries are not dependent on each other.  It will reduce time by five times.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is "Not really", but you can achieve the effect by using DBMS_SCHEDULER to create and submit these as jobs timed to run at the same time. Clunky, and you have to code for things like waiting for all to complete, handling single or multiple failures etc. I wouldn't recommend it, but it's a good technical exercise to learn about the scheduler and job control.

The other issue you will have with this approach, since they are writing to the same table, locking/contention, which means you might not get the linear improvements you think. You can take steps to improve throughput, but that's another topic.

How about a different approach? You have 5 INSERTs to the same table with SELECT from different tables. Based on your example you could try using the PARALLEL hint and combine the INSERT into 1 with the SELECT queries UNIONED:

```
INSERT /*+ PARALLEL ( mast_tab, 8 ) */
INTO mast_tab
SELECT * FROM class1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM class2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM class3
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM class4
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM class5
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this, however I have not written anything like this myself. I did find an explanation on how to do a similar thing on the internet, so you might want to read these articles:

http://www.dba-oracle.com/plsql/t_plsql_parallel_functions.htm

http://www.dba-oracle.com/r_execute_pl_sql_in_parallel.htm

Make sure you build a check in your look to see if all the parallel processes have actually completed before committing the changes though.

EDIT: In the example you give, you insert a bunch of different tables into a single table. Combining the INSERT statements into one statement, then letting the Oracle parallelization do its thing might also give you a performance gain. This isn't always possible, but it is in your example. Your query would end up looking like this:

```
BEGIN
FOR I IN (SELECT id FROM mast_tab)
LOOP

  INSERT /*+ PARALLEL(mast_tab) */ INTO mast_tab
     (SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(class1) */ * FROM class1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(class2) */ * FROM class2
     UNION ALL
     SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(class3) */* FROM class3
     UNION ALL
     SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(class4) */* FROM class4
     UNION ALL
     SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(class5) */* FROM class5)
     ;

  COMMIT;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with DBMS_SCHEDULER or DBMS_JOB package. 
It allow to run it as separated background jobs that may run in parallel.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add much compared to the other, more detailed answer, which discusses the potential use of DBMS_SCHEDULER